# WAMP slow to respond

Tags: windows, apache, windows-7, wamp, vhosts

When i access any virtual host on my installation of wamp, the browser hangs for about 4-5 seconds. After months of dealing with this issue, I found that the only way to fix it is to run ipconfig /flushdns. This seems to be a temporary fix that works sometimes.

What's really odd (and reproducible) is that once i access a page though a vhost, after it hangs for 4-5 seconds it's pretty fast to respond each time after the first. But, if i leave the browser for about 1-2 minutes and then go back to refresh the page, it hangs again for 4-5 seconds again. It's almost like Apache is resetting something up each time I wait a minute or two between requests.

Has anyone else experienced anything like this?

Comment: What kind of server name(s) are you using and who are they being managed by - a DNS server? The hosts file?

Comment: @Pekka - I use the windows hosts file. Looks like this:
127.0.0.1   sandbox.local
127.0.0.1   foo.local www.foo.local

etc....